# ng lint while watching for file changes during ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to run the 'ng lint' with ng serve, ng-build also with the watch, Is there any way to run ng lint while watching for file changes during ng serve?

Answer (score 0):

No, currently, there is no such an option. However, tslint is integrated into many popular IDE and Editors.